# How to use TemplateBinding with Visual State Groups?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How do I use `TemplateBinding`s with `VisualStateGroup`s?

My custom control has just one part: a `Border` element. If you click and hold the border element, it switches visual states.

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyControl
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Box", Type = typeof(UIElement))]
    public class MyControl : Control
    {
        public static DependencyProperty MyBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "MyBackground", typeof(Color), typeof(MyControl)
            );

        public Color MyBackground
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(MyBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        static MyControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            UIElement button = GetTemplateChild("PART_Box") as UIElement;
            button.MouseDown += (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) => { VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Alternate", false); };
            button.MouseUp += (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) => { VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Default", false); };
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Default", false);
        }
    }
}
```

The template for my control includes the definitions for the visual states. The "Default" state just has a solid red background, the "Alternate" state uses the dependency property background via a `TemplateBinding`.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyControl">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
                    <Border x:Name="PART_Box"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup Name="MyStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Default">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation To="Red" Duration="0"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Alternate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation To="{TemplateBinding MyBackground}" Duration="0"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BackgroundBrush" />
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I'm using my control like this:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyControlTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyControl;assembly=MyControl"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <custom:MyControl MyBackground="Blue" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I'm seeing is that the red background loads just fine, but when I click and hold, the background just becomes transparent (or possibly white) instead of blue.

If I remove the `TemplateBinding` from my template, and instead hard-code blue, the background switches as expected.

Is it possible to use `TemplateBinding` inside of a `VisualStateGroup` storyboard?

Comment: It is known that neither binding nor DynamicResource can be used with animation. You can find many precedent questions searching by animation and binding.

Comment: Usually, you would define brushes and colors as resources. In your case MyControl and your animation would reference the same resource (preferably as StaticResource).

Comment: @BionicCode so the best approach would be to use fixed colors in my custom control, then override the control template in my main window to customize the colors?

Comment: Your code also won't work because you can't animate a Brush with a ColorAnimation. Let me post an example

Comment: Also your Style does not contain an element named "BackgroundBrush"...

Answer (score 1):

`TemplateBinding` won't work in this context. You would have to use `RelativeSource` with the `TemplatedParent` parameter.
Alternatively, because the `Border` named "PART_Box" binds to the templated parent's `Background` property too, you could also use the `Border` as color source.

Furthermore, you can't animate a `Brush` with a `ColorAnimation`. As the type name suggests, it only animates `Color`. This means you must cast the `Brush` to the more specialized type (e.g., `SolidColorBrush`) in order to be able to reference the `Color` property:

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="Alternate">
  <Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation To="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)}"
                    Duration="0"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)" />
  </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: you can't apply a brush within a ColorAnimation, but you can definitely change the color of an existing brush. i have a brush named "BackgroundBrush" near the bottom of the template, so i'm tweaking the brush instead of directly setting the border's background.

Comment: how can i develop an intuition of which types of bindings / references are valid in which contexts? does the `VisualStateGroups` overwrite some context of the `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: This are just framework details. **1)** Stepping into a property like `MyProperty.NestedProperty` or using a cast like in the above `Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)` is called *nested property syntax* **2)** `TemplateBinding` is a MarkupExpression to "shortcut" `Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` **3)** `TemplateBinding` is very primitive and doesn't allow nested property syntax (it also doesn't support value converters).

Comment: ==> if we need a more complex binding to the templated parent, like in our case where we have to use nested property syntax in order to cast `Background` (of type `Brush`) to `SolidColorBrush`, we have to fallback to the more verbose `Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`.